# Restoring Whatsapp history doesn't work

Tags: iphone, icloud, restore, whatsapp.app

I just got a new IPhone and downloaded Whatsapp. Every time I open Whatsapp, a message saying that the history is being restored from ICloud is displayed and a few seconds later a window pops up saying that the history has been successfully restored. The problem is that it keeps doing the same thing every time I open Whatsapp, so I can't use the app at all.

What can I do?

Comment: has it actually restored it ?

Comment: @Buscar웃: How can I tell?

Comment: turn off wifi or icloud

Comment: @Buscar: How do I turn off icloud?

Comment: @Buscar: I have tried to open Whatsapp when on flight mode and get the same restoring cycle.